# Typescript + Angular "controller as" Sidewaffle template doesn't work out of the box

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.4, sidewaffle

Forgive me for the wall of code that follows, but there's only one small change per block and each change is commented.

I'm trying to use the Angular+Typescript "controller as" template that came with the Sidewaffle template pack. This is what the template looks like out of the box. The only modifications I've made to the template here are comments, whitespace, and renaming 'app1' to 'app':

```
interface ItestControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
    vm: testController;
}
interface ItestController {
    greeting: string;
    controllerId: string; //This won't work...
    changeGreeting: () => void;
}
class testController implements ItestController {
    static controllerId: string = "testController"; //...because this is static.
    greeting = "Hello";

    constructor(private $scope: ItestControllerScope, private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
    }
    changeGreeting() {
        this.greeting = "Bye";
    }
}
app.controller(testController.controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', ($scope, $http, $resource) =>
        new testController($scope, $http, $resource)
    ]);
```

The first thing to note is that it won't even compile due to the static `controllerId` member on the controller class and the `controllerId` member that is required by the `Icontroller` interface. Since the members of the interface need to be implemented in the instance side of the class's type, this won't work.

That's annoying, but easy to get around, though we lose some of our type checking by doing so:

```
interface ItestControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
    vm: testController;
}
interface ItestController {
    greeting: string;
    changeGreeting: () => void;
}
class testController implements ItestController {
    //we leave the static member on the class and remove the member
    //from the interface
    static controllerId: string = "testController";
    greeting = "Hello";

    constructor(private $scope: ItestControllerScope, private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
    }
    changeGreeting() {
        this.greeting = "Bye";
    }
}
app.controller(testController.controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', ($scope, $http, $resource) =>
        new testController($scope, $http, $resource)
    ]);
```

Now this compiles, but the problem is how the call to `app.controller()` gets translated to javascript. Instead of passing the constructor function to `app.controller()` directly, it's wrapped in an anonymous function and what we end up with is a constructor within a constructor:

```
var testController = (function () {
    function testController($scope, $http, $resource) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$resource = $resource;
        this.greeting = "Hello";
    }
    testController.prototype.changeGreeting = function () {
        this.greeting = "Bye";
    };
    testController.controllerId = "testController";
    return testController;
})();
app.controller(testController.controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$http', '$resource',
    //Why won't this work? Why would we want to do this in the first place?
    function ($scope, $http, $resource) { 
        return new testController($scope, $http, $resource); 
    }
]);
```

Now when we try to use the "controller as" syntax in a view, Angular can't find the aliased controller- the view binds to an empty object.

The best I can tell, the Typescript template *should* look like this:

```
interface ItestControllerScope extends ng.IScope {
    vm: testController;
}
interface ItestController {
    greeting: string;
    changeGreeting: () => void;
}
class testController implements ItestController {
    static controllerId: string = "testController";
    greeting = "Hello";

    constructor(private $scope: ItestControllerScope, private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
    }

    changeGreeting() {
        this.greeting = "Bye";
    }
}
//Now we're passing the controller constructor directly instead of
//wrapping the constructor call in another constructor
app.controller(testController.controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$http', '$resource',testController]);
```

Which compiles into this javascript:

```
var testController = (function () {
    function testController($scope, $http, $resource) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$resource = $resource;
        this.greeting = "Hello";
    }
    testController.prototype.changeGreeting = function () {
        this.greeting = "Bye";
    };
    testController.controllerId = "testController";
    return testController;
})();

app.controller(testController.controllerId,
    ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', testController]);
```

which works fine. So I have two main questions:

1. Why would you ever want to wrap the controller constructor in a lambda to hand to Angular's `controller()` method instead of handing over the constructor directly?
2. Why would the template have a static member on a class that its trying to enforce with a member on the interface that the class implements?

My only guess is that both of these problems were not problems in some earlier combination of versions of Typescript and Angular, but I wouldn't know as I'm fairly new to both. I'm using Typescript v1.4 and Angular v1.3.14

Comment: i can't seem to find a way to insert the typescript version of the templates, any help please?

Comment: Your typescript version isn't dependent on the version of the templates that are installed. It's dependent on the version of Typescript that you have installed + the version # defined in your project.

Comment: i'm sorry, i couldn't express my situation accurately. What i faced is not being able to find the typescript templates at all in the insert element dialog. But now like magic they are here. I didn't change anything. Maybe it was just me not paying enough attention. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [source code on Github](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/commit/3498aeed52acf5ce61ff3537d9968539a96b438f) reveals that the template in question has been "updated  to be Typescript 1.0 and Angular 1.3 compatible," so with some combination of previous versions of both Angular and Typescript all the stuff in the template must have worked at some time in the past.

The two questions I had are addressed in the updated files, and the changes are similar to those that I made to get things running. The Sidewaffle template pack just hasn't been updated accordingly yet.

**Update:** As of this writing the latest version of Sidewaffle templates include fixed templates.

Comment: No. TypeScript 0.8 (first version) had the same semantics of `class` so nothing changed. Angular 1.0 still called controllers with `new` and supported `$inject` so nothing changed. The template was just JavaScript developers grasping TypeScript incorrectly.

Comment: @basarat You may be right, but that repository is curated by some awfully smart individuals. I'd be surprised if they let mistakes like that slide by, especially for this long. As of this writing those updates were only made 17 days ago.

Comment: @basarat including you!

Comment: I made some additional changes to the templates so they work with Angular but still use TypeScript classes, and Sayed just published a new version of SideWaffle today so these issues should be resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would you ever want to wrap the controller constructor in a lambda to hand to Angular's controller() method instead of handing over the constructor directly?

You wouldn't. I don't https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E

> Why would the template have a static member on a class that its trying to enforce with a member on the interface that the class implements

About `controllerId: string; //This won't work...` Having a member on an interface and implementing that interface with a class means *instances of the class will have this member*. What you are trying to say however is *the class has this member*. This cannot be done by *implementing an interface*.

You can ensure this in other ways :

```
var mustHaveId:{controllerId:string};

class Fail{}
class Pass{static controllerId = "Pass"}

mustHaveId = Fail; // Error 
mustHaveId = Pass; // Pass
```

Comment: I'm in agreement with you on this, I just don't understand why the Sidewaffle template(s) are built this way. Surely at one point the code in the first code in my question worked.

Comment: [I answered my own question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861916/typescript-angular-controller-as-sidewaffle-template-doesnt-work-out-of-the/28866520#28866520) The template must have worked prior to Typescript v1.0 and Angular v1.3.